# How to get twitter user's profile picture (not pixeled) by having user's screen_name or user's id?

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

I know that there are tons of similar questions, but NONE worked for me. I have an Oauth twitter system integrated into my website. I can get user's id, screen_name, etc. However, I don't know how to get user's profile photo in original size or full size. Please, if you're going to answer this question, don't copy and paste a bunch of document library from twitter, because that's Mandarin Chinese to me and I've already tried to do it with no success. I just need an url where I can replacethe user's id into one part of the url and then put that url as img's src to show it in html (obviously, I'd do so by executing an "echo" in the oAuth php file. Thanks beforehand.

My code:

```
<?php

if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}

require 'autoload.php';

use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

define('CONSUMER_KEY', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'); // add your app consumer key between single quotes
define('CONSUMER_SECRET', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'); // add your app consumer secret key between single quotes
define('OAUTH_CALLBACK', 'http://www.chapatelo.com.ar/chm/peticiones/callback.php'); // your app callback URL
if (!isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
    $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
    $request_token = $connection->oauth('oauth/request_token', array('oauth_callback' => OAUTH_CALLBACK));
    $_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $request_token['oauth_token'];
    $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];
    $url = $connection->url('oauth/authorize', array('oauth_token' =>     $request_token['oauth_token']));
    header("Location: " . $url);
} else {
    $access_token = $_SESSION['access_token'];
    $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET,     $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);
    $user = $connection->get("account/verify_credentials");

    $_SESSION["id"] = $user->id;
    $_SESSION["usuario"] = $user->screen_name;
    $_SESSION["start"] = time();
    $_SESSION["expire"] = $_SESSION["start"] + (3600 * 60);

    echo '<img src="https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=' . $user->screen_name . '"/>'; //Of course, this echo doesn't show any image...
}

?>
```